# how to get some rows from dataset using sql sentence?

Tags: c#, winforms

i have `dataset` that contains rows

```
MyTbl
=====
Name | Age
----------
aa | 23
bb | 90
cc | 2
dd | 1
ee | 14
```

i need to fill datagrid with all rows that the `age > 5`

```
aa | 23
bb | 90
ee | 14
```

i try this:

```
dataGrid1.DataSource = Main.dsParts.Tables[1].DefaultView.RowFilter = "Age > 5";
```

and this:

```
dataGrid1.DataSource = Main.dsParts.Tables[1].Select("Age > 5");
```

but it not work !, how to do it ?

thanks in advance

Comment: What is the DataType of the Age column, i suppose its string thats why its not working

Comment: It should seem something like MyTbl.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(Int32));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Main.dsParts.Tables[1].DefaultView.RowFilter = "Age > 5";
dataGrid1.DataSource = Main.dsParts.Tables[1].DefaultView;
```

The `RowFilter` sets the condition, but just setting it doesn't return a new view to display; but from that point on, the `.DefaultView` will contain only those rows that match that criteria.

Comment: You are right but then the second scenario should have also very well worked.